# How can I enable asynchronous swapping using a kswapd thread in a cgroup resolution?

Tags: swap, cgroups

I would like to enable active swapping (using a background daemon) on my cgroup even before the entire system is suffering memory shortage.

I have a 128GB Linux host and a cgroup that is limited to use only 16GB. I would like active swapping to take place when the memory usage of the process within the cgroup approaches 16GB. Instead what I see is passive/synchronous swapping taking place (i.e.: only upon receiving a page fault because of cgroup limitations, the system starts evicting pages).

This synchronous mechanism slows the process down and is highly inefficient.

How can I enable kswapd asynchronous thread that will work in the resolution of my cgroup (before the entire system experiencing a problem)?

Thanks...